# Navigate between pages using QStackedLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a multipage application in which I require to navigate between pages using `QStackedLayout`. I've made two buttons **Previous** and **Next** to navigate.

The problem is that the buttons stop functioning after 2-3 clicks. I guess it's got something to do with the way I'm trying to retrieve the value of `CurrentIndex()` in the `if` statement.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.stack_lay = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()

        cam_widget = Page1(self)
        self.stack_lay.addWidget(cam_widget)
        self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(cam_widget)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.stack_lay)
        
        self.previous = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Previous')
        self.previous.clicked.connect(self.previous_page)
        self.previous.setDisabled(True)
        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Next')
        self.next.clicked.connect(self.next_page)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addWidget(self.previous)
        layout.addWidget(self.next)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def previous_page(self):
        if self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 1:
            page1_widget = Page1(self)
            self.stack_lay.addWidget(page1_widget)
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(page1_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(True)
            self.next.setDisabled(False)

        elif self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 2:
            page2_widget = Page2(self)
            self.stack_lay.addWidget(page2_widget)
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(page2_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(False)
            self.next.setDisabled(False)

    def next_page(self):
        if self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 0:
            page2_widget = Page2(self)
            self.stack_lay.addWidget(page2_widget)
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(page2_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(False)
            self.next.setDisabled(False)
        
        elif self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 1:
            page3_widget = Page3(self)
            self.stack_lay.addWidget(page3_widget)
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(page3_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(False)
            self.next.setDisabled(True)

class Page1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page 1')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(lay)

class Page2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page2, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page 2')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(lay)

class Page3(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page3, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page 3')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(lay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why are you creating pages every time? Just create them at the beginning, then use `setCurrentIndex` accordingly.

Comment: @musicamante, you mean in the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.stack_lay = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()

        self.page1_widget = Page1(self)
        self.page2_widget = Page2(self)
        self.page3_widget = Page3(self)
        self.stack_lay.addWidget(self.page1_widget)
        self.stack_lay.addWidget(self.page2_widget)
        self.stack_lay.addWidget(self.page3_widget)
        self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(self.page1_widget)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.stack_lay)
        
        self.previous = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Previous')
        self.previous.clicked.connect(self.previous_page)
        self.previous.setDisabled(True)
        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Next')
        self.next.clicked.connect(self.next_page)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addWidget(self.previous)
        layout.addWidget(self.next)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def previous_page(self):
        if self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 1:
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(self.page1_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(True)
            self.next.setDisabled(False)

        elif self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 2:
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(self.page2_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(False)
            self.next.setDisabled(False)

    def next_page(self):
        if self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 0:
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(self.page2_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(False)
            self.next.setDisabled(False)
        
        elif self.stack_lay.currentIndex() == 1:
            self.stack_lay.setCurrentWidget(self.page3_widget)
            self.previous.setDisabled(False)
            self.next.setDisabled(True)

class Page1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page 1')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(lay)

class Page2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page2, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page 2')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(lay)

class Page3(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page3, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page 3')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(lay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```